# Как в R убрать английские слова во всем тексте, оставив только русский текст?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, r

Моя задача - проверить грамматику русского текста, но package, который я использую, отмечает анлийский текст как ошибку. Так что единственным выходом является убрать английские буквы из текста, оставив только пунктуацию и русский текст. Есть ли код для чего-то подобного?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

например, можно воспользоваться функцией gsub:

```
> gsub("[A-Za-z]", "", "текст с bukvami")
[1] "текст с "
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант, использовать функцию `str_remove_all` пакета `stringr`

```
> library(stringr)
> txt <- "смешанный текст с english и русскими словами (words)"
> pttrn <- "[A-Za-z]"
> str_remove_all(txt, pttrn)
[1] "смешанный текст с  и русскими словами ()"
```